# RPi freezes after booting

Tags: raspbian

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi B+ and I am very new to it. I installed NOOBS Raspbian OS on it and everything worked fine. Now I wanted to build and install kernel image on it. So I downloaded the kernel source code for that, and followed the steps mentioned on their website: 
(http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation).

I booted the Pi, and now the kernel freezes after booting, with the final boot messages shown below. I am using GPIO pins 2,6,8,10 for serial console here, and I don't have a GUI. I found a similar issue [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19537/raspberry-pi-freezes-during-boot) and tried the safe mode option in `config.txt`, but nothing worked. Can any one help me regarding this issue ?

Note: Though the console freezes, I am able to see console messages when I plugged in wireless adapter or keyboard to the Pi.

Below are the last boot messages and the screen shot showing the same.

```
[    4.214068] smsc95xx v1.0.4 

[    4.277477] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:9b:bc:d2
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably the kernel you built is broken, perhaps the modules were not all written to /lib/modules.  Did you keep the old image on the SD card?  You could try booting that.

Comment: I know there are some problems with certain sd cards if you can try a different sd card

Comment: any updates here?

Comment: I used the same sd card before with the NOOBS image, it works fine. @ Rainey

Comment: Now I installed wheezy-rasbian.img NOOBS image and it works fine on the same sd card.With the pre-build NOOBS image the boot messages it is showing after the freeze point(that is happening with the custom build images) are: udevd[156]: starting version 175
bcm2708-i2s bcm2708-i2s.0: Failed to create debugfs directory
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck. Please comment if you find any thing weird from the above messages. Thanks